# ActiveMQ Topic - Messages not getting persisted in database

Tags: activemq-classic, persistence, persistent-storage, jms-topic

I have enabled persistence in ActiveMQ broker. It is saving messages in db table for messages in Queue. **Problem**
ActiveMQ is not saving messages in database for TOPICS. Configuraiton attached below. I am looking for messages in table **activemq_msgs**.

If I check this table for a queue, it is getting populated. But messages in topics are not getting persisted.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="Central-Dev-Broker" persistent="true"  offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="8" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="3000" useJmx="true">
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>

            <policyEntry queue=">">
              <deadLetterStrategy>
                <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
              </deadLetterStrategy>
            </policyEntry>

          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <!--kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/-->
        <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>
    <plugins/>
    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>
</broker>


 <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_activemq?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
  </bean>
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

messages for a topic are only saved if there is a online Subscribers or offline Durable Subscribers.
if there is no subscribers to the topic, messages are lost.

additionally, you have this config below, wich  remove inactive durable subscribers after 3s!!
so all messages persisted for Durable Subscribers are removed.
http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html

```
  offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="8" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="3000"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have disabled offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout by setting the value to "-1". But still messages are not getting saved in database table activemq_msgs

Comment: Is there any durable subscriber offline ??

Comment: Yes there is. I am testing the scenario where a durable subscriber is both online and offline and activemq gets restarted. And the messages are getting lost. I tested this by sending 10000 messages in the and before all get consumed, i stopped and restarted the activemq

Comment: So, test this scenario : create a durable subscriber -> stop it -> send messages to the topic -> verify messages on mysql table -> connect the durable subscriber to consume messages -> verify that mysql table is empty

Comment: you can do after that this scenario : create a durable subscriber -> stop it -> send messages to the topic -> verify messages on mysql table -> restart the broker -> connect the durable subscriber to consume messages -> verify that mysql table is empty

Comment: I have tested this as well. Subscriber receives messages as soon as it restarts. But messages never come to dB table, which makes the problem

Comment: Database does not show any row in MSG's table when subscriber goes off or comes up again.

Comment: jmsTemp.send(dest, new MessageCreator() {
 
 @Override
 
 public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
  Message message = session.createTextMessage("some message");
 
  message.setJMSExpiration((subType.getMsgTimeToLiveMins())*60000);
  
  message.setJMSDestination(new ActiveMQTopic("test.nnm.data.auditer"));
  
  message.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
  
  return message;
}});

Comment: producer seems ok, i never used jdbcPersistenceAdapter , try by removing below policyEntry  and restart broker and test  <policyEntry topic=">" >
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>

Comment: It didn't worked :(. I tried going back to KahaDB persistence and same result over there i.e. message loss after restart.

Comment: can you update your question with durable subscriber code, ActiveMQ WebConsole screenshot, startup logs